# Why aren't my input getting appended into the array? (Python)

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
example = "house"
example = example.upper()
guess = ''
array = []

def guess_function(guess):
    guess = input("Enter a letter:  ")
    guess = guess.upper()
    while ord(guess) < 64 or ord(guess) > 90:
        print("Invalid input, please try again..")
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    return guess

def populate_array(array):
    while len(array) < 26: #I have this condition so I can have every letter    in the alphabet
        guess_function(guess)
        array.append(guess)
        print(array)
        populate_array(array)
print(populate_array(array))
```

I expect this code to append each letter I guess into the empty list. But for some reason I get this instead: [''], and each time I put in a new input it just adds an extra set of ''. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an empty string (`guess = ''`) to `guess_function`, without assigning the returned value from `guess_function` to a variable. Then you're appending to your array the empty string, `guess`, instead a variable holding the returned value from `guess_function`, which is why your array is filled with `''`.

I've added comments to a cleaned up working version of your code, describing my choices.

```
# Initializing a "guess" variable in global scope is unnecessary, because it's unused.
array = []

# This function doesn't need any arguments, because it handles all logic inside.
def guess_function():
    guess = input("Enter a letter:  ")
    guess = guess.upper()
    while ord(guess) < 64 or ord(guess) > 90:
        print("Invalid input, please try again..")
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    return guess

def populate_array(array):
    while len(array) < 26:
        # Call the function and assign to a variable the result.
        guess = guess_function()
        array.append(guess)
        # Because of the while loop, no need to recursively call the self-same function.
        # Instead of printing the array each time, return the array.
        # This way, the calling function can determine how to display the array.
    return array


print(populate_array(array))
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. It works perfectly fine. Haven't been using Python for a long time, as a matter of fact it's my first language so I'm still getting used to some things. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned 'guess' as a global variable at the top, but you need to add 'global guess' if you plan on accessing it in your functions. As it stands you are using it as a local variable and returning but never assigning the result to something usable to append to your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
guess = input("Enter a letter:  ")
```

This assignement doesn't assign the output of `input(...)` to the global variable `guess` but to the parameter `guess` that is not accessible from the outside.

A better version would be

```
example = "house".upper()
all_guesses = [] # Not used by me, but you'll use it

def get_guess():
    guess = input("Enter a letter:  ")
    guess = guess.upper()
    while ord(guess) < 64 or ord(guess) > 90:
        print("Invalid input, please try again..")
        guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    return guess

def populate_array():
    array = []
    while len(array) < 26:
        guess = get_guess()
        array.append(guess)
    return array
print(populate_array())
```

Global state should be avoided if you don't really, absolutely need it. `guess` does not have to be global, because it is not used outside of the `get_guess`